# Azure monitor and deployment slots

Tags: azure, monitoring

My question is actually quite simple: if I have a webapp with a deployment slot and a monitor that checks the health of webapp in some way (connections, cpu time or the like) , if I do a swap, what is the monitor watching? The new webapp or the old?

I would like to think it is always watching the current production slot, but I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment slots share the same resources. The percentage of CPU used is what is taken by all slots combined.
After a swap, it should still monitor the production slot.

Comment: But what about conne tions, handles etc? Is those still monitored on the production slot?

Comment: Everything on the app service plan is shared, everything on the app service itself is not. Connections are measured on the app service and thus measured per slot.
After a swap the monitor is pointing to the actual slot that handles the production load.

Comment: yes. Cpu time is pr app service. Cpu usage is pr webplan etc. Where can I read that it always monitor production slot?